# Why HTML5 Canvas does not draw when script is placed inside head tag?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

When drawing graphics with HTML `canvas` while putting `<script>` in your document's `<head>` does not works. For example:

```
<head>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        if(canvas.getContext("2d"))
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
        ctx.lineTo(200,100);
        ctx.stroke();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
        Your browser does not support the canvas element.
    </canvas>
</body>
```

But you do get the expected results when `<script>` is placed inside `<body>`. Since you can place the `<script>` anywhere inside `<head>` then why isn't this working with `canvas`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's because you are trying to access the canvas element before it exist in the DOM. Place your code inside a `window.onload` or after the canvas is loaded, or place it after the DOM element in HTML (script at the end of body).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You HTML is not rendered yet, so 
    document.getElementById("myCanvas")
Cannot find the myCanvas element.  Whereas if you place the code after, the HTML is rendered, so it is able to find it.

If you want to place it in the head, use an event on document load to render it, so it executes after the HTML is rendered.

Check this code:

```html
<head>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        if(canvas.getContext("2d"))
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
        ctx.lineTo(200,100);
        ctx.stroke();
     });   
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
        Your browser does not support the canvas element.
    </canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: I've placed the code inside `$(document).ready(function() { //CODE });`. Still not working

Comment: I've updated with code.  You can also check this code pen: http://codepen.io/poushy/pen/JEOBKp

Comment: If you are using jquery, make sure to initialize jquery before the script.

Answer (score 1):

The DOM has not loaded yet, you should put your script inside the callback function of the "OnDOMContentLoaded" event

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    //your script
});
```

Or you can put your script at the end of the body